# Promise is not returned in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, promise

`getNameFromDB()` in myService returns a promise. When I call this function from `home.page.ts`, the promise is not returned. I've checked different suggestions on SO, but none could solve the problem. Here is my code:

myService.ts:

```
public getNameFromDB(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let param = {
          table: "info",
          columns: "*",
          where: "id=1"
        };
        this.dbService.select(param).then(
          (res: []) => {
            if (res.length != 0) 
              if (res[0]['name'] != '')
                this.nameIsSet = true;
              
            console.log('Name is set? ', this.nameIsSet);
            resolve('success');
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error('Error while reading info: ', err);
            reject(err);
          }
        ).catch(e => {
        console.error('[myService.ts] catch error: ' + e);
        reject(err);
    });
    }) // close promise
  } //close function
```

home.page.ts:

```
 this.myService.getNameFromDB().then(
   (res)=>{ console.log('1. Name is set.')},
   (err)=>{ console.log('2. Some error.')}      
 )
 .catch(e => {
    console.error('3. catch error: ' + e);
  });
```

What is the code behavior? In the console I can see:
`name is set? true` which means `getNameFromDB()` in `myService`, is executed and should return  `resolve('success');`, but none of the three logs in the `home.page.ts`, are shown.

It seems to me, the promise is not returned since neither logs in `then` nor the log in `catch` are shown!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ionic issue but a general TS/JS question. You should not be using  `return new Promise()`, but instead use try/catch and async/await.

```
public async getNameFromDB() {
  try {
   const param = {
    table: "info",
    columns: "*",
    where: "id=1"
  };

 const res: [] = await this.dbService.select(param);

 if (res.length > 0 && res[0]['name'] !== '') {
  this.nameIsSet = true;
 }

 console.log('Name is set? ', this.nameIsSet);
 return 'success';
 } catch (err) {
  console.error('Error while reading info: ', err);
  throw err;
 }
```

}

then to call:

```
try {
  const res = await this.myService.getNameFromDB();
  console.log('1. Name is set.');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('2. Some error: ' + err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @StackoverBlows for replying. The problem was not with promise or how I have called the function .... The problem was that DB was not initialized properly.